# Unity 2D Shooter - Arm Rotation

Tags: unity-game-engine, transform, unityscript, unity3d-2dtools

I'm making a 2D platformer game where the player has an arm that points towards the mouse cursor. This mechanism is used to aim the player's weapon. However, I am experiencing some glitches when rotating the arm.

I know the reason why I am getting these errors: The arm (in the hierarchy) is a child of the player, and what I'm doing to the player is flipping (inverting) its `transform.localScale.x` value whenever it moves in a specified direction, so that the player sprite looks in the given direction. Since the arm is a child of the player, its own `transform` is flipped as well, making it look in the same direction as the player, which is what I want. However, this causes some errors with the arm rotation. Since the arm's `transform.localScale.x` value is flipped, the rotation is all messed up, and I can't figure out how to solve it.

Here are some example scripts for moving the player and arm. They are simplified so that you can read it better.

```js
// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    var input = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

    if(input > 0) {
        if(!facingRight) {
            ChangeOrientation(gameObject, new Vector3(-1,1,1));
            facingRight = !facingRight;
        }
    }

    if(input < 0) {
        if(facingRight) {
            ChangeOrientation(gameObject, new Vector3(-1,1,1));
            facingRight = !facingRight;
        }
    }

    rbody.velocity = new Vector2(speed * input, rbody.velocity.y);

}

public static void ChangeOrientation (GameObject g, Vector3 changeBy) {
    var newTransform = g.transform.localScale;
    newTransform.x *= changeBy.x;
    newTransform.y *= changeBy.y;
    newTransform.z *= changeBy.x;
    g.transform.localScale = newTransform;
}
```

And my arm rotation script:

```js
void Update () {
    //rotation
    Vector3 mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
    mousePos.z = 0;

    Vector3 objectPos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint (transform.position);
    mousePos.x = mousePos.x - objectPos.x;
    mousePos.y = mousePos.y - objectPos.y;

    float angle = Mathf.Atan2(mousePos.y, mousePos.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 0,
                                                      (PlayerRunMovementController.facingRight ? angle : angle )));
}
```

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: Add components that you are using for the Unity3D so we can help you better. We didn't know if you're using the Sprite Component or are you using an Individual Objects to construct your Game Player. 
Tips for you: Do not make your controls Calculate every Update Key pressed.

You have a static method. Change Orientation and It is called every frame. Normally it is fine, but Creating multiple objects every time will hit your performance really bad. You have newTransform being created and being assigned. If you get into a big project. It could be a nightmare.

Comment: No, it isn't. It is not created every frame.

Comment: ofcourse it is not, it is only created everyframe if you hold a Key from horizontal.